# How to Stop Searchkit Grouping / Lists from Truncating Data

Tags: searchkit

I am running a search in searchkit - Its for event participants and I have the results grouped by a custom field. Its great, but the email field (list) seems to truncate any data over 1024 Characters excluding spaces. Is there any way to change this? I ran a test on other fields too - it seems that the results will truncate. 5.69.5

Edit: Tested in Dmaster - could not replicate.

Comment: If you couldn't replicate in dmaster then either you are using an older version and the issue has been recently fixed, or dmaster doesn't have enough sample data to give you a column over 1024 characters.

Comment: Yes it does - https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsearch#/edit/45
demo - demo

Comment: Could it be a database issue?

Comment: You might want to try upgrading